# Why does the use of dependencyManagement in maven usually not lead to problems?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

I understand that dependencyManagement in Maven gives you great benefits in terms of avoiding different versions of dependencies in sub-poms and in using one (and only one) version of a dependency.

At the same time, I am struggling to understand why overriding transitive dependencies by dependencyManagement is a safe thing to do.
Let's say that we have a dependency *D* which is set to version 2.0 with dependencyManagement.
Another dependency - *C* - also uses *D*, although it depends on *D* in version 1.0.
With dependencyManagement, I am setting this transitive dependency up to 2.0.
Isn't this dangerous? After all, *C* relies on the API and the implementation of version 1.0 - what if breaking changes have been made between the versions 1.0 and 2.0 of *D*?

Comment: What you described is a very possible problem and i personally had the joy fixing maven dependencies on some of our projects because they had conflict which lead to  "NoSuchMethodException" being thrown. But its not an everyday occurrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because *D 2.0* is backward compatible.
So *D 2.0* provides all APIs, functionalities as *D 1.0*, and thus *C* can use it.

If *D 2.0* is **not** backward compatible, then you have a conflict. You might need to upgrade *C*, or find a lower version of *D* that all your dependencies can happily rely on.

You can use `mvn dependency:tree` to resolve conflicts as mentioned [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a safe thing to do.

It can lead to the problems you describe.

But as you cannot have more than one version of a dependency (at least, not without shading), you need to pick one or let Maven decide. The latter is in most cases more dangerous than picking a reasonable version yourself.